# Can I programmatically determine targeted .NET framework version?

Tags: .net, target-framework

I would like to be able to display the version of the .NET framework a windows form or wpf project is targeted at and display it in the title bar of the app.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Environment.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) property to get the currently loaded version of the CLR.

Comment: Actually, this gives the CLR version, not the Framework version.